# VS code auto suggestions for React does not work properly

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for React developments. Although I have installed the React plugin such as ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native extensions, it does not give correctly suggestions.

Reinstallation was also failed to give the result.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to install ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets extension in your Visual Studio Code. You can find it on [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) or just search for it in VS Code extension section. It is very easy to use it and it really facilitates coding in React.

Comment: Works bad on my ubuntu 18.04 and vsc,trigger on every third attempt.